# Representing Separate Related Entities in API

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm working on an API for something similar to stackoverflow where you have Users and Questions and I'm torn between two options for designing my resources.

I have a `/user` resource for getting user info and a `/question` resource. However if i wanted to get all the Questions a user raised, would it be more sensible to have it as

option 1 - `/question/user/{userId}/`

option 2 - `/user/{userId}/questions`

Questions can exist without Users (i.e even if a user deleted himself off the app, the questions will still persist. However I'm still unsure if the API itself should go for structure 1 or 2. Thoughts?

Comment: Voted to close for attracting primarily opinion-based answers only. In REST the form of the URI is not of relevance and should furthermore not convey meaning to a client to avoid [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Clients should base their decision around the usage of link-relation names or on some other accompanying meta-data such as human-readable text to render, similar to the Web where a description of the target content is more expressive than the actual link itself, instead of the form of the URI .

Answer (score 1):

> I'm still unsure if the API itself should go for structure 1 or 2. Thoughts?

REST doesn't particularly care about URI design, so long as the identifiers are consistent with the production rules described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  That's part of the point - the client can follow a link without needed to decode the semantics of the identifier.

That said... one of the interesting bits of RFC 3986 is the specification of relative references, which allows you to use [dot-segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) as a short hand for specifying other identifiers in the same hierarchy

```
//a/b/c/d + ../g  === //a/b/g
//a/b/c/d + ../../g === //a/g
```

So one possible tie breaker when considering the organization of your path segments is how much utility you can extract from dot segments

```
/question/user/{userId}/  + .. === /question/user/
/user/{userId}/questions/ + .. === /user/{userId}/
```

Aside from URI manipulation, the "hierarchy" of identifiers is an artificial construct, in this sense: general purpose components will consider that the resources are unrelated even though they have overlapping path hierarchies.  You can, for example `DELETE /b/c`, and general purpose components will assume that `/b/c/d` and `/b/c/e` are both unaffected.